# What is the best way to install node from a tar file on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

The tar file I downloaded is a binary (not source) distribution. I read an article that said to run tar --strip-components 1 -xzf  in /usr/local but if I do this I cant see an simple way to remove everything when I want to upgrade the version later. I could un-tar it with the prefix intact, i.e. tar -xzf  but i'm not sure which environment variables would need to be set to get man pages and everything else working, at minimum I guess I would need to set the path. Is there a 'best practice' for this kind of installation?

Comment: `nvm`  manages my node installations much better. I do not know your use case, so i cannot comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install node is described on the [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).

The setup script will create a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` to update the installed package version .

You can see the content of the `./setup` script:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x
```

There are may features :

- adding a NodeSource signing key
- automatic update
- check your system to install the appropriate package to your OS
- Install the required package (`apt-transport-https` , `lsb-release` ..)
- It is safe than installing a node tar file.

Comment: This is fine if I want to install version 8.x but if I want to install the latest version I think would need use either a binary or source tar file.